# Delete a node in the middle of a singly linked list given only the node. C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Before I submit my code here I want to know if my idea is correct, as I already the "correct" answer to this problem.

Is it possible to solve this question by finding the position of the given node, and then using the regular 'Delete at a given position' function? So basically the previous node will point to the next node of the given node. i.e, If s is given node, ptr is previous node, then ptr->next = s->next. Is this correct?

Comment: yes it is correct, that how it's usually done

Comment: Why not draw boxes with lines denoting the links, and see how you would do this on paper?

Comment: _"Before I submit my code here I want to know ..."_ Pffffr .... That's probably something what you can ask in a chat room here. Do you have a particular problem with your code or concept?

Comment: How do you find the previous node of a given node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.

Let's say the Node to delete is *delNode*.

**The solution you suggested has 2 parts:**

1. Search for its *index* in the list.
2. then delete the Node at[*index*].

Time Complexity is O(n) - where n is size of the list. (part 1 worst case is O(n)).
There are no problems with this solution.
If Node *delNode* isn't found, no deletion will occur.

**A different solution:** (With its Pros & Cons).

Assume the Nodes before and after *delNode* are A and B respectively.
A has its A.data and A.next, and *delNode* has its *delNode.data* and *delNode.next* (i.e: *delNode.next* == B).
Deletion of *delNode* means that after its deletion, A.next == B.

But without using a search we can NOT change A.next because A isn't reacheble from *delNode* (Singly Linked List).

So instead of searching *delNode* we can try manipulate the list like this:
*delNode.data* = *delNode.next.data* (Simplier: delNode = B.data).
*delNode.next* = *delNode.next.next* (delnode.next = B.next).

These changes keeps delNode Object in Memory, but its State was changed and all the content of B were copy to delNode. So delNode right now is actually B, and the because B.next (==C) was also copied to delNode.next, the next Node after delNode is C.

before: Head--> ... --> A --> delNode --> **B** --> C --> ...

after:  Head--> ... --> A --> delNode(== B state includes B.next == C) --> C --> ...

So the Node who's been deleted is actually **B** and B only.

**A quick summary:**

**Pros:**

- Time Complexity is O(1).

**Cons:**

Cases the solution is not applicable:

- *delNode.next*   ==   *Null*.
- *Polymorphic List*.
  For a List with Polymorphic types there's a problem. For example: **Car** and **Bus** are both has the same SuperClass **Vehicle**, and the list contains **Vehicle** objects.
  If delNode is a Car, and B is a Bus, the Idea of copy B state to delNode is **WRONG**! These objects have different concrete types, therefore this solution is not applicable to this case.

**Last Thing**

C++ implementation - Don't forget to ***delete(B)***.